# Cool animated line over an image with Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I made this cool animation of a horizontal line animated from top to bottom over an image of a datamatrix.

Please feel free to improve the animation effect.

[AnimatedLine.kt](https://gist.github.com/cyril-tl/0320b754a31b733897877c4fd6f0bd0e)

[image]

Comment: Very nice and clear starting point. Thank you. I used it as a base for an enhanced variant: https://github.com/kotoMJ/kotox-android/blob/main/kotox-mobile-playground/src/main/kotlin/cz/kotox/playground/ui/scannerline/ScannerAnimatedLine.kt

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use a `Spacer` and a `Divider`.

The `Spacer` takes a `height` animated between 0 and the max size of the container (here a `Box`).

The `Divider` will be "pushed" to the bottom of the `Box` as the `Spacer`'s height increase.

```
@Composable
fun AnimatedLine(
    boxSize: Dp = 100.dp,
    animationDuration: Int = 2000) 
{
    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()

    val heightAnimation by infiniteTransition.animateValue(
        initialValue = 0.dp,
        targetValue = boxSize,
        typeConverter = Dp.VectorConverter,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = keyframes {
                durationMillis = animationDuration
                0.dp at 0 // ms
                boxSize at animationDuration / 2
                0.dp at animationDuration with FastOutSlowInEasing
            }
            // Use the default RepeatMode.Restart to start from 0.dp after each iteration
        )
    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(boxSize),
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.datamatrix_jojo),
            contentDescription = "start scanning",
            modifier = Modifier.size(boxSize),
        )
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(heightAnimation))
            Divider(
                thickness = 4.dp, color = Color.Red,
                modifier = Modifier.width(boxSize - 6.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```